# Create output JTL or log files when running with runTestNonGui argument

Tags: jmeter, smartmeter

SmartMeter does not create output JTL or log files when running with `runTestNonGui` argument.
It creates output files just fine if I open GUI and run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Listener / [et@sm - Controller Summary Report](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-et-sm---controller-summary-report) to your test plan. It outputs to results/[TIMESTAMP]-report.jtl.
The reason it works in GUI mode is that this component is added automatically (if missing). Unfortunately, it is not added automatically in NO GUI mode.

Comment: Thanks Vernjan. It works. I was able to get jtl and create summary report without GUI.  Your answer and this blog entry helped. https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/smartmeter-load-test-report